# OpenAM failed to create iPlanetDirectoryPro cookie sometimes in Chrome?

Tags: openam

Sometimes, at OpenAM Log-in page, right ID/Password failed to Log-in. (Chrome Browser)
  - After Log-in, Browser return to Log-in page.

In this situation, I checked the Authentication Error, but no error found.

And in the same environment, Internet Explorer succeeded to Log-in.

In Chrome, I opened developer window, and I found iPlanetDirectoryPro cookie value is null.

I think, After successful authentication, Browser failed to create iPlanetDirectoryPro cookie value.

Then, I unchecked 'Enable phishing and malware protection'.

After that, Chrome Log-in succeeded.

And after one success, though I return to check 'Enable phishing and malware protection', Chrome continue to succeed to Log-in.

Why this phenamenon occurs?

Need to fix-up something?

Comment: by default OpenAM uses a domain cookies. If the browser considers your OpenAM FQDN as public suffix (https://www.publicsuffix.org/) it has to drop the domain cookie. Just trace the HTTP response. If you see a 'Set-Cookie' HTTP response header but the cookie is not kept by the browser then this is the root cause.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard (Thank you Mr. Thalmayr ^^).

Our domain name, I can't find it in the public suffix lists.

Well... In this time, that phenomenon doesn't occur. So, once again it arrises I'll check the Response header and cookies status.

I'll keep in mind your advice. Thanks again~